# Do prime ideals in polynomial ring generate prime ideals in the ring of holomorphic functions?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, cv.complex-variables, complex-geometry

Suppose that $I \subset \mathbb C[z_1,\dots, z_n]$ is a prime ideal. Consider the ideal $I_{hol}$ in the ring of holomorphic functions $f: \mathbb C^n\to \mathbb C$ generated by polynomials from $I$.

Is $I_{hol}$ prime?

Comment: In general no. The standard example is the nodal curve, $y^2=x^2+x^3$, which generates a prime ideal in $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$, but is not a prime when you extend it to the holomorphic functions.

Comment: @Mohan I was going to post this, but $\langle y^2-x^2-x^3 \rangle$ IS prime in the ring of entire functions. It just factors on any open set where $\sqrt{1+x}$ may be defined (since $y^2-x^2-x^3 = (y-x\sqrt{1+x})(y+x\sqrt{1+x})$). The more usual question to ask is about the ring of germs at holomorphic functions at $(0,0)$, where your answer is right, but I'm not sure for entire functions.

Comment: Proof that $y^2-x^2-x^3$ is prime in entire functions: Let $C = \{ y^2=x^2+x^3 \}$ and note that $C$ can be parametrized as $(t^2-1,t^3-t)$. Suppose $fg=y^2-x^2-x^3$. Then $f(t^2-1, t^3-t) g(t^2-1, t^3-t)=0$. The ring of entire functions of $t$ is a domain so one of these factors is $0$, say $f(t^2-1, t^3-t)=0$. Then $f(x,y)$ vanishes on $C$, so $f(x,y)/(y^2-x^2-x^3)$ is bounded near the points of $C$ so, by Riemann's extension theorem, $f(x,y)/(y^2-x^2-x^3)$ extends to an entire function.

Comment: @DavidSpeyer Yes, I too was thinking of germs and not the entire plane.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Edit. I added some lemmas to address the issue raised by David Speyer and the OP.**  The books by Grauert and Grauert-Remmert are wonderful sources.  The proofs in those books are the "correct" arguments, using "sledgehammers" as little as possible.  Even though it is a sledgehammer, Hironaka's Resolution of Singularities Theorem does *quickly* establish the result.  Also, I will also use the smaller sledgehammer ("club hammer"?) of GAGA.

For every locally finite type $\mathbb{C}$-scheme $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$, denote by $(i_X,i_X^\#):(X^\text{an},\mathcal{O}_X^{\text{an}})\to (X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ the associated complex analytic space.  For every topological space $S$, denote by $C^0_S(\mathbb{C})$ the sheaf of continuous, $\mathbb{C}$-valued functions on $S$.  For every complex analytic space $(S,\mathcal{O}_S)$, denote by $u_S:\mathcal{O}_S\to C^0_S(\mathbb{C})$ the natural homomorphism of sheaves of $\mathbb{C}$-algebras.

**Question 0.** For a finite type $\mathbb{C}$-scheme $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$, what is the kernel of $u_{X^{\text{an}}}:\mathcal{O}_X^{\text{an}}\to C^0_{X^{\text{an}}}(\mathbb{C})$?

For the nilradical $\mathcal{N}\subset \mathcal{O}_X$, certainly $\mathcal{N}\cdot \mathcal{O}_X^{\text{an}}$ is contained in the kernel.  Most of the comments for the question and for this answer focus on the problem of proving that the kernel equals $\mathcal{N}\cdot \mathcal{O}_X^{\text{an}},$ which it does.  One approach uses "analytic reducedness" of the local rings $\mathcal{O}_{X,p}/\mathcal{N}_p$ at $\mathbb{C}$-points $p\in X^{\text{an}}$.  Not all reduced local Noetherian rings are analytically reduced.  However, **excellent local rings** that are reduced are analytically reduced, cf. the Wikipedia page for excellent local rings.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Excellent_ring#Properties

The approach here to the kernel of $u_{X^{\text{an}}}$ is different, using Hironaka's Resolution of Singularities.

**Lemma 1.** For every finite type $\mathbb{C}$-scheme, the associated complex analytic space is a complex manifold if and only if $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ is a smooth $\mathbb{C}$-scheme.  In particular, if $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ is a smooth $\mathbb{C}$-scheme, then the homomorphism $u_{X^\text{an}}$ is injective.

**Proof.** This is local, so we may assume that $X$ is affine.  Then the result follows from the Jacobian criterion for smoothness (on the algebraic side) and the complex analytic version of the Implicit Function Theorem (whose hypothesis is the rank condition on the Jacobian as in the Jacobian criterion).  For a complex manifold, there are local biholomorphisms with polydisks, whose sheaf of holomorphic functions is manifestly a subsheaf of the sheaf of continuous functions. **QED**

**Lemma 2.** For every closed immersion of smooth $\mathbb{C}$-schemes, $(j,j^\#):(Y,\mathcal{O}_Y)\to (X,\mathcal{O}_X)$, with ideal sheaf $\mathcal{I}$, the analytic ideal sheaf $\mathcal{I}\cdot \mathcal{O}_X^{\text{an}}$ equals the subsheaf of $\mathcal{O}_X^{\text{an}}$ of germs of holomorphic functions that vanish identically on the underlying set of $Y^{\text{an}}$.

**Proof.** Since $\mathcal{O}_X^\text{an}$ is flat as a sheaf of $i_X^{-1}\mathcal{O}_X$-algebras, the following sequence is a short exact $$0\to \mathcal{I}\cdot \mathcal{O}_X^{\text{an}} \to \mathcal{O}_X^{\text{an}} \to j^\text{an}_*\mathcal{O}_Y^{\text{an}}\to 0.$$  By the previous lemma, $\mathcal{O}_Y^{\text{an}}$ is a subsheaf of $C^0_{Y^\text{an}}(\mathbb{C})$. **QED**

**Lemma 3.** For every closed immersion $(j,j^\#):(Y,\mathcal{O}_Y)\to (X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ of finite type $\mathbb{C}$-schemes, if $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ is smooth and quasi-projective, and if $(Y,\mathcal{O}_Y)$ is reduced, then the conclusion from Lemma 2 holds.

**Proof.**  By Hironaka's Resolution of Singularities Theorem, there exists a projective, birational morphism, $$(\nu,\nu^\#):(\widetilde{X},\mathcal{O}_{\widetilde{X}})\to (X,\mathcal{O}_X),$$ and a smooth closed subscheme, $$(\widetilde{j},\widetilde{j}^\#):(\widetilde{Y},\mathcal{O}_{\widetilde{Y}})\to (\widetilde{X},\mathcal{O}_{\widetilde{X}}),$$ with ideal sheaf $\widetilde{\mathcal{I}}$ such that $\nu_*\widetilde{\mathcal{I}}\cdot \mathcal{O}_X$ equals $\mathcal{I}$.  By Serre's GAGA, also $\nu^{\text{an}}_*\widetilde{\mathcal{I}}^{\text{an}}$ equals $(\nu_*\widetilde{\mathcal{I}})^{\text{an}}$, so that the same result holds for the associated analytic spaces.

Associated to the short exact sequence on $\widetilde{X}^{\text{an}}$, $$0 \to \widetilde{I}\cdot \mathcal{O}_{\widetilde{X}}^{\text{an}} \to
\mathcal{O}_{\widetilde{X}}^\text{an}\to \widetilde{j}_*^\text{an}\mathcal{O}_{\widetilde{Y}^{\text{an}}} \to 0,$$ there is an exact sequence on $X^{\text{an}}$, $$0 \to \nu^\text{an}_*\widetilde{I}\cdot \mathcal{O}_{\widetilde{X}}^{\text{an}} \xrightarrow{e} 
\nu^\text{an}_*\mathcal{O}_{\widetilde{X}}^\text{an}\to 
\nu^\text{an}_*\widetilde{j}_*^\text{an}\mathcal{O}_{\widetilde{Y}^{\text{an}}}.$$  Finally, by Lemma 1, also the natural map from the third term to the pushforward of $C^0_{\widetilde{Y}^\text{an}}(\mathbb{C})$ is injective.  Thus, we also have injectivity of the induced homomorphism from the cokernel of $e$ to the pushforward of $C^0_{\widetilde{Y}^{\text{an}}}(\mathbb{C})$.

Since $X$ is already smooth, the natural homomorphism $\nu^\#:\mathcal{O}_X[0]\to R\nu_*\mathcal{O}_{\widetilde{X}}$ is a quasi-isomorphism compatible with arbitrary base change.  In particular, $\mathcal{O}_X\to \nu_*\mathcal{O}_{\widetilde{X}}$ is an isomorphism.  By GAGA, also $\mathcal{O}_X^{\text{an}} \to \nu_*^{\text{an}}\mathcal{O}^{\text{an}}_{\widetilde{X}}$ is an isomorphism.  Together with the previous paragraph, it follows that the natural homomorphism from $\mathcal{O}_{X^\text{an}}/\mathcal{I}\cdot \mathcal{O}_{X^\text{an}}$ to the pushforward of $C^0_{\widetilde{Y}^\text{an}}(\mathbb{C})$ is injective.  This homomorphism factors through the natural homomorphism, $$\mathcal{O}_{X^\text{an}}/\mathcal{I}\cdot \mathcal{O}_{X^\text{an}} \to j^{\text{an}}_*C^0_{Y^\text{an}}(\mathbb{C}).$$ Thus, also this second natural homomorphism is injective. **QED**

**Lemma 4.** For every finite type $\mathbb{C}$-scheme $(Y,\mathcal{O}_Y)$, the scheme is reduced if and only if the homomorphism $u_{Y^{\text{an}}}$ is injective.  In particular, for the nilradical $\mathcal{N}\subset \mathcal{O}_Y$, the nilradical of $\mathcal{O}_{Y}^\text{an}$ equals $\mathcal{N}\cdot \mathcal{O}_Y^\text{an}$.

**Proof.**  Since $\mathcal{O}_Y^\text{an}$ is flat over $i_Y^{-1}\mathcal{O}_Y$, the nilradical of $\mathcal{O}_Y^\text{an}$ contains $\mathcal{N}\cdot \mathcal{O}_Y^\text{an}$.  Thus, if $(Y,\mathcal{O}_Y)$ is nonreduced, then $u_{Y^\text{an}}$ is not injective.

Conversely, assume that $(Y,\mathcal{O}_Y)$ is reduced.  To prove that $u_{Y^{\text{an}}}$ is injective and that $\mathcal{N}\cdot \mathcal{O}_Y^{\text{an}}$ equals the entire nilradical, it suffices to work locally.  Locally there are closed immersions of $(Y,\mathcal{O}_Y)$ into affine space.  Thus, the result follows from the previous lemma. **QED**

**Lemma 5.** For every finite type, affine $\mathbb{C}$-scheme $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$, for every surjection of coherent $\mathcal{O}_X$-sheaves, $\phi:\mathcal{F}\to \mathcal{G}$, the induced map $\phi^{\text{an}}(X^{\text{an}}):\mathcal{F}^{\text{an}}(X^{\text{an}})\to \mathcal{G}^{\text{an}}(X^{\text{an}})$ is surjective.

**Proof.** Probably there is a more direct proof, but this also follows from vanishing of the higher sheaf cohomology of coherent analytic sheaves on a Stein complex analytic space.  Since $\mathcal{O}_{X^\text{an}}$ is flat over $i_X^{-1}\mathcal{O}_X$, the kernel of $\phi^{\text{an}}$ equals the coherent analytic sheaf associated to the kernel of $\phi$.  Since $X$ is affine, the complex analytic space $X^{\text{an}}$ is Stein.  By vanishing of the higher cohomology of coherent analytic sheaves on a Stein complex analytic space, the first sheaf cohomology of $\text{Ker}(\phi^{\text{an}})$ vanishes.  Surjectivity of $\phi^{\text{an}}(X^{\text{an}})$ follows by the long exact sequence of sheaf cohomology.  **QED**

**Proposition.** For a finite type $\mathbb{C}$-scheme $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ that is smooth and affine, for every closed subscheme $(Z,\mathcal{O}_Z)$ that is integral and with ideal sheaf $\mathcal{I}$, also the ideal $I^\text{hol}:=\mathcal{I}(X)\cdot \mathcal{O}_X^\text{an}(X^{\text{an}})$ is a prime ideal in $\mathcal{O}_X^\text{an}(X^\text{an})$.

**Proof.** If a product $g\cdot h$ of holomorphic functions is contained in $I^\text{hol}$ then it vanishes on $Z^\text{an}$, since each element of $I(X)$ vanishes on $Z^\text{an}$.  Since $Z$ is irreducible, the smooth locus $Z_{\text{sm}} = Z\setminus Z_{\text{sing}}$ is a dense open subscheme that is an integral, smooth $\mathbb{C}$-scheme.  The zero loci of $g$, and $h$ on $Z^\text{an}_{\text{sm}}$ are complex analytic subvarieties of a connected, complex manifold.  If neither of these complex analytic subvarieties equals all of $Z^\text{an}_{\text{sm}}$, then they are each nowhere dense. In that case, also the union is nowhere dense, contradicting the hypothesis that $g\cdot h$ vanishes on $Z^\text{an}$.  Thus, one of the factors, say $g$, vanishes identically on $Z^\text{an}_{\text{sm}}$.  Since $Z^\text{an}_{\text{sm}}$ is dense in $Z^\text{an}$ for the analytic topology, also $g$ vanishes on $Z^\text{an}$.  By Lemma 3, $g$ is a section of $(\mathcal{I}\cdot \mathcal{O}_X^\text{an})(X^\text{an})$.

Fix a finite generating set $f_1,\dots,f_r$ of the ideal $I = \mathcal{I}(X)$.  By Lemma 5, the induced map, $$(\mathcal{O}_X^{\text{an}})(X^\text{an})^{\oplus r} \to (\mathcal{I}\cdot\mathcal{O}_X^{\text{an}})(X^\text{an}), \ \ (u_1,\dots,u_r)\mapsto u_1f_1 + \dots + u_rf_r,$$ is surjective.  By construction, the image is in $I^{\text{hol}}$.  Therefore $I^{\text{hol}}$ equals all of $(\mathcal{I}\cdot\mathcal{O}_X^{\text{an}})(X^\text{an})$.  Thus, $g$ is an element of $I^{\text{hol}}$. **QED**

Comment: I was trying this approach, and it wasn't clear to me that $\mathcal{I}$, defined as the image of this map, is the full ideal sheaf of $Z$ in $\mathcal{O}^{an}$. How do you rule out the possibility that $\mathcal{O}^{an}/\mathcal{I}$ has nilpotents?

Comment: @DavidSpeyer. "How do you rule out the possibility that $\mathcal{O}^{\text{an}}/\mathcal{I}$ has nilpotents?"  If you do not mind using a sledgehammer, you can use resolution of singularities.  There is a proper, birational morphism $\nu:\widetilde{Z}\to Z$ where $\widetilde{Z}^{\text{an}}$ is a complex manifold.  Thus, $\nu^{\text{an}}_*\mathcal{O}_{\widetilde{Z}^{\text{an}}}$ is a sheaf of reduced $\mathbb{C}$-algebras.  Since $\mathcal{O}_{Z^{\text{an}}}$ is a sheaf of $\mathbb{C}$-subalgebras, it is also reduced.

Comment: @JasonStarr, thanks a lot, your answer is very helpful for me!
Could you kindly comment a little bit more about ruling out nilpotents? I came from analysis and not familiar with this sledgehammer

Comment: @JasonStarr
I am really sorry, but I miss even the following: suppose that $\cal{O}^{an}/\cal{I}$ does not have nilpotents. Why $g$ belongs to $\cal{I}$ locally then? This requires some version of Hilbert Nullstellensatz for germs of holomorphic functions as I can understand. But I know such a version Hilbert Nullstellensatz only in the case when the ideal is prime.

Comment: @JasonStarr I figured out a non sledge hammer approach. It is easy to see that, if $(A, \mathfrak{m})$ is a (noetherian) local ring without nilpotents, then the completion $\widehat{A} = \lim_{\infty \leftarrow n} A/\mathfrak{m}^n$ also has no nilpotents. Let $z$ be any point of $Z$, and let $(A, \mathfrak{m})$ be the local ring of $Z$ at $z$. Then the stalk of $\mathcal{O}^{an}/\mathfrak{I}$ injects into $\widehat{A}$, so it also has no nilpotents. I might write up a longer version of this tonight if I get time.

Comment: That's a wonderful answer with an unexpected conclusion (to me) to a very interesting question.

Comment: @JasonStarr, thanks a lot for such a detailed answer! I am sorry again, but there is still one thing that I don't understand:(

Comment: @JasonStarr, : in the proof of Lemma 3 you use the sequence $0\to \nu_*^{an} \tilde{I}\cdot \mathcal{O}^{an}_{\tilde{X}} \to \nu_*\mathcal{O}^{an}_{\tilde X} \to \nu_*^{an}\tilde{j}_*^{an}\mathcal{O}_{\tilde Y}^{an}$ and the isomorphism $\mathcal{O}_X^{an}\simeq \nu_*\mathcal{O}_{\tilde X}^{an}$ to conclude that $\mathcal{O}_{X^{an}}/\mathcal{I}\cdot \mathcal{O}_{X^{an}}\to \nu_*^{an}\tilde{j}_*^{an}\mathcal{O}_{\tilde Y}^{an}$ is injective.

Comment: @JasonStarr, But I see only how to conclude that $\mathcal{O}_{X^{an}}/\nu_*^{an} \tilde{I}\cdot \mathcal{O}^{an}_{\tilde{X}}\to \nu_*^{an}\tilde{j}_*^{an}\mathcal{O}_{\tilde Y}^{an}$ is injective. How do you argue that $\mathcal{O}_{X^{an}}/\nu_*^{an} \tilde{I}\cdot \mathcal{O}^{an}_{\tilde{X}} = \mathcal{O}_{X^{an}}/\mathcal{I}\cdot \mathcal{O}_{X^{an}}$

Comment: Since $\nu_*\widetilde{\mathcal{I}}\cdot \mathcal{O}_X$ equals $\mathcal{I}$ as $\mathcal{O}_X$-submodules of $\mathcal{O}_X$, the $\mathcal{O}_X^{\text{an}}$-submodules that they generate are also equal.

Comment: @JasonStarr, but why $\nu_*^{an} \left ( \tilde{\mathcal{I}} \cdot \mathcal{O}_{\tilde{X}}^{an} \right )$ is the same as $\mathcal{O}_{X}^{an}$ module that $\nu_*\tilde{\mathcal{I}}$ generates? As far as I understand it is not true in general that if $\nu_* \mathcal{F}_1\simeq \mathcal{G}_1$ and $\nu_*\mathcal{F}_2\simeq \mathcal{G}_2$ then $\nu_*(\mathcal{F}_1\otimes \mathcal{F}_2)\simeq \mathcal{G}_1\otimes \mathcal{G}_2$. What do I misunderstand?

Comment: @DavidSpeyer, it seems that your statement that the completion of reduced local Noetherian ring is reduced is false: https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02JD

Comment: @Mikhail.  The statement that David Speyer wrote is true for "good" local Noetherian rings (and that starts down the path to "excellence").  Also, regarding your question to me: for a projective morphism such as $\nu$, the fact that the analytification of the higher derived images equal the higher derived images of the analytification follows by GAGA.

Comment: @JasonStarr, you mean that analytification of direct image is direct image of analytification (not only for {\it higher} direct image)?

The argument of David Speyer looks very nice, it would be wonderful if one can argue in such a way. Could you write here some condition of "goodness" of the ring?

Comment: @Mikhail.  I am not going to write out the statement of the GAGA theorem.  There is a nice expose in SGA 1 about GAGA (that extends the results to proper morphisms).  Regarding analytic reducedness of excellent local rings, this is under "properties" on the Wikipedia page for "excellent ring": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Excellent_ring

Comment: @JasonStarr, OK, I will believe you about GAGA. In any case the David Speyer approach mixed with your ideas definitely gives the proof. Thanks a lot for the discussion anyway, my understanding has been improved a lot!!!

Comment: @Mikhail Thank you! I did not realize this was subtle, so thank you for the reference.

Comment: @DavidSpeyer, could you also briefly explain why $\mathcal{O}^{an}/\mathcal{I}$ injects into $\widehat{A}$? Or give any reference?

Sorry for so many questions, but I really want to understand this fact properly